# Saving compatibility with old-style links while moving to Symfony2

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, symfony

I'm moving web-app from pure php to Symfony2 and going to save working old links like http://domain.com/index.php?task=help&term_id=2 (which in Symfony2 are like http://domain.com/2/?task=help).
What should I do to do this? (add some rewrite rules to .htaccess in web dir or some other things...)

UPD: Count and position of query params are variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to solve my problem next way:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} term_id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ /%1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Ok, but this is the solution to your problem, and not to your question.

Comment: @AttilaFulop actually this is solution to my problem _and_ my question.(may be except next thing: term_id sits in query_string and rewrited part, but for my situation it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

I would add rewrite rules to htaccess like:

Updated:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^task=([a-zA-Z]+)&term_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php/%2/?task=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to work correctly with query strings. I tested it with Apache 2.2

Comment: I usually add multiple conditions for each of them